# I need to grep a code from file1 and file2 and write it to file3

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with my product names which contain special characters and spaces in between the name. At the end there's a code of that product.

In file2 I would have only names of the product without codes.

I need a command which will look inside the file and search for a product name and grab the code from that product name and write it into file3.

An example image what I want to do is [here](https://i.ibb.co/KyrWtty/ABCDEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEe.jpg)

[image: Example]

Can you help me out with a correct command?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and contributors trying to help will have to type-copy content when trying to analyze/reproduce your problem. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.

Comment: Why don't you provide some sample of the files?

Answer (score 2):

From `grep` manual:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
Obtain patterns from FILE, one per line. The empty file contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing. (-f is specified by POSIX .
```

So the following command greps for matching lines from file2 in file1.

```
grep -f file2 file1
```

Then you just need to take the last field from the output of the first command.

```
grep -f file2 file1 | awk '{ print $NF }' > file3
```

#### Caveats

As @they mentioned in the comment, there are few caveats to be aware of:

1. From the comment:

> Note that using `file2` as patterns with `grep` will treat the text
> therein as regular expressions. It means certain characters like `.` and
> `*`, might match unexpectedly.

For instance, If `file2` includes the line `This is a dot.`, it might also match `This is a dotx` in `file1`.

In order to overcome this issue, you could use add the `-F/--fixed-strings` flag to treat all the characters in the pattern as literals:

```
-F, --fixed-strings
       Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. (-F  is specified by POSIX.)
```

2. As @they wrote:

> Also note that a regular expression is not anchored by default, which
> means that a line starting `MM706` would also match lines starting with
> `QMM706`.

A certain workaround could be using the `-w/--word-regexp` flag:

```
-w, --word-regexp
       Select  only  those  lines  containing  matches  that form whole  
       words.  The test is that the matching substring must  either  be
       at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
       constituent character.  Similarly, it must be either at the  end
       of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
       Word-constituent  characters  are  letters,  digits,   and   the
       underscore.
```

It solves the issue only partially, as `QMM706` will not be matched by `MM706`. However, it still doesn't ensure only patterns that appear at the beginning of the line would be matched.

Either and both `-F` and `-w` could be conjoined with `-f` to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Note that using `file2` as patterns with `grep` will treat the text therein as regular expressions.  It means certain characters like `.` and `*`, might match unexpectedly. Also note that a regular expression is not anchored by default, which means that a line starting `MM706` would also match lines starting with `QMM706`.  You also assume that the cases (uppercase/lowercase) are the same between all files.  This is all fine if you actually declare these assumptions in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @they, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to get the last space-delimited field from each line.

```bsh
awk '{ print $NF }' file.txt
```

By default, `awk` splits each input line into fields on spaces and tabs (one or several of these blank characters delimits two fields from each other).  The number of fields that this results in is stored in the special variable `NF`.  Accessing the last field may be done using `$NF`.

---

Assuming that your `file2.txt` only contains a subset of the products and you want to get the product codes from `file.txt` only for that subset, and assuming that that number in the last field of `file2.txt` is unique for the product, you may use

```bsh
awk 'NR == FNR { nr[$NF] = 1; next } ($(NF-1) in nr) { print $NF }' file2.txt file.txt
```

This reads the numbers at the end of `file2.txt` into the array `nr` as keys.  It then compares the number in the second to last field on each line from `file.txt` with the stored numbers in `nr` and prints the last field if the number is present as a key in the array.

This is obviously untested as I'm not going to sit down and write down the data from your image.

Answer (score -1):

Try also

```
grep -f file2 file1 | grep -o '[^ ]*$'
```